# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: xcode

Got messed up in my project so I created new project and added the same files in it as in my previous project but after compilation I am getting following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController", referenced from: objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I tried everything, I clean and build.Reset simulator.Even cleaned cache but it did not helped.I am using xcode 4.4.1, please anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your MainViewController.m file is not added to the target. Click on the file in the navigation pane on the left. Then, in the right panel of Xcode, make sure that the MainViewController has target membership in your app by checking the box next to your app.